# geo element must be an array or object: type: "Point"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I tried post request like this

> "{    "imgUrl": "Server\Pictures\i14182109167", "text": "Myself in
>   seoul",   "tag": ["seoul", "tour"],   "geometry" : {"type": "Point","coordinates": [80,
>   -27]} }"

The error causes

> 'Can\'t extract geo keys: { _id:
>   ObjectId(\'5b8e204455526366f86a6383\'), tag: [ "seoul", "tour" ],
>   date: new Date(1536041028423), imgUrl:
>   "Server\Pictures\i14182109167", text: "Myself in seoul", geometry: {
>   type: "Point", coordinates: [ 80, -27 ], _id:
>   ObjectId(\'5b8e204455526366f86a6384\') }, __v: 0 }  geo element must
>   be an array or object: type: "Point"' }

even I added "type": "Point" in post request but, why?

```
const geoSchema = new Schema({
  type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Point',
      index: '2dsphere'
  },
  coordinates: {
      type: [Number]
  }
});

const memoSchema = new Schema({
  imgUrl: {
    type: String
  },
  text: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  tag: {
    type: [String]
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Memo'
  },
  geometry: geoSchema
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error, tried several schema declarations, until **I fixed by this implementing this design:**

#### 1. Create a new schema, which has Point as a property.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Point} = require('mongoose-geojson-schema');

const pointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Point'],
    required: true
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true
  }
});
```

#### 2. Schema for the object including above as a property:

```
const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      location: {
        type: pointSchema,
        required: true
      }
)
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemsSchema);
module.exports = Item;
    enter code here
```

#### 3. Finally, my controller **succesfully** instantiates the object like this:

```
  var geolocation =
  {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [
      lng,
      lat
    ]
  };


 const item = new Item({
     description: req.body.description,
     location: geolocation
 })
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: have followed this, still same error: geo element must be an array or object: type: "Point"

Answer (score 0):

I changed geometry to loc it worked!
but, I don't know why...

Comment: Its because loc isn't geo Indexes. You could change it to anything it will worked. But it will not indexed

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue even after doing everything mention here. After spending too much time on this problem I get to know that if we save a default value it will work correctly.
Just follow the above answer and add

```
location: {
  type: pointSchema,
  default: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [0, 0],
  },
  required: false,
},
```

And delete the previous documents if any document has location.